# Ordo - Calculating c & n₀

Tags: c, big-o, complexity-theory

I have this assignment where I have some problems. I have a hard time knowing what to do with my data I've collected.

My assignment is to calculate the constant c in ordo and as well n₀.

We have an unknown code that we execute via the terminal. We can choose how many elements we want to process. The more elements, the longer time it takes for the program to run.

At the end of the program we get a number on how long the program took to complete.

Here is the collected data:

```
Input   |  time (s)
--------+----------
1000    |   0.0015
1000    |   0.0016
1000    |   0.0015
2000    |   0.0063
2000    |   0.0063
3000    |   0.0063
4000    |   0.0281
4500    |   0.0344
5000    |   0.0453
6000    |   0.0672
7000    |   0.0953
8000    |   0.1265
9000    |   0.1656
10000   |   0.2078
11000   |   0.2547
12000   |   0.3062
15000   |   0.4875
20000   |   0.8953
25000   |   1.4125
30000   |   2.0390
35000   |   2.8750
40000   |   3.6641
50000   |   5.7641
50000   |   5.7438
70000   |   11.4781
75000   |   13.7312
80000   |   15.0828
85000   |   17.1156
90000   |   19.8610
100000  |   23.2328
110000  |   28.8032
130000  |   40.6344
```

[image: plotted data set]

The thing is: How do I move on from here? I have my guess looking at the chart is telling me that the complexity is O(n²).

Is there any tips for me how to take the next step and calculate c & n₀?

[image: this is ment by 'c']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general its not a good idea to "compute" the complexity of a function by measure the time it takes to run on different input.

E.g. Lets say the function uses big integers and large strings 50% each. Now you have a special compiler extension that speeds up the big integer arithmetics massivly. Now it is possible to miss how the runtime scales with the integer input.

If you have to get an idea of the complexity without the source code of the function, you could use the run time `t` as input to your "complexity function" f(t). To show that the function is in O(n²) you only have to give a `g(t)`, `c` and `n₀`, such that f(t) ≤ c⋅g(t) holds for all t ≥ n₀, It does not have to be exact.

In your case it would be ok to choose `g(t) = t² + 1`, `c = 1` and `n₀ = 0`.
You also could use  `g(t) = 1/4⋅10⁻⁸⋅t²+1` with `c = 1` and `n₀ = 0` (red)
or `g(t) = 1/4⋅10⁻⁸⋅t²` with `c = 1` and `n₀ = 40000` (blue).

[image]

But notice: You cannot do this exact. It is also possible that this result turns out as wrong if you test 10¹⁰ as input. If you want to get the exact complexity you have to take a look at the code.